# Finding the sequence of $n$ length where it is possible to make every value from one to as high of an integer as possible by adding adjacent values

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there any easy way of finding the sequence of $n$ length where it is possible to make every value from one to as high of an integer as possible by adding adjacent values (lone numbers are allowed and the sequence is cyclic)?

For example sakes I'm going to ignore the fact that we want the sequence with the largest sum of its values. Say we have the sequence $\left\{ {1, 2, 6, 4}\right\}$. This can make:

$1 = 1$
$2 = 2$
$1 + 2 = 3$
$4 = 4$
$4 + 1 = 5$
$6 = 6$
$4 + 1 + 2 = 7$ (cannot be $1 + 6 = 7$ as they are not adjacent in the sequence)
$2 + 6 = 8$
$1 + 2 + 6 = 9$
$6 + 4 = 10$
$6 + 4 + 1 = 11$
$2 + 6 + 4 = 12$
$2 + 6 + 4 + 1 = 13$

Comment: Note that $4$ and $1$ are not adjacent, so $11$ and $5$ can't be made. (Or is the sequence cyclic?)

Comment: @Ragnar I believe that's what Jim meant by "going from end to start".

Comment: Yes sorry, it is cyclic.

Comment: Very interesting problem! The trivial upper bound of $n^2-n+1$ is attainable for $n\leq 6$, but the pattern seems to break $n=7$ where the maximum seems to be $39$ rather than the predicted $43$. On the other hand, it's once again reachable for $n=8$ and $n=9$...

Comment: @Peter, can you show us your constructions for these values of $n$?

Comment: My search has found the following optimal sequences: $(1)$, $(1,2)$, $(1,2,4)$, $(1,2,6,4)$, $(1,2,10,2,5)$, $(1,2,5,4,6,13)$, $(1,1,2,9,5,15,6)$ (the imperfect one), $(1,2,10,19,4,7,9,5)$, $(1,2,4,8,16,5,18,9,10)$; although it's quite possible there are others of equal length.

Comment: @Peter, how do you get a sum of 4 from $(1,2,10,2,5)$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson By correcting the typo: $(1,3,10,2,5)$ :-)

Comment: So I did a search for solution up to length 12 and got the following: N=1 # 
{1}

N=2 # 
{1,2}

N=3 # 
{1,2,4}

N=4 # 
{1,2,6,4} * 
{1,3,2,7}

N=5 # 
{1,3,10,2,5}

N=6 # 
{1,2,5,4,6,15} * 
{1,2,7,4,12,5} * 
{1,3,2,7,8,10} * 
{1,3,6,2,5,14} * 
{1,7,3,2,4,14}

N=7 # 
-

N=8 # 
{1,2,10,19,4,7,9,5} * 
{1,3,5,11,2,12,17,6} * 
{1,3,8,2,16,7,15,5} * 
{1,4,2,10,18,3,11,8} * 
{1,4,22,7,3,6,2,12} * 
{1,6,12,4,21,3,2,8}

Comment: Well this comment thing is too limited for more but there are 4 representative solutions for N=9, 6 for N=10, 0 for N=11, and 18 for N=12. Representative of solutions obtained by reversal and rotation that is.